# How to interpret $|\nabla u|$ when using distributions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

In Sobolev spaces, to define the respective norm, we need to be able to interpret $||\nabla u||_{L^2(\Omega)}=\left( \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 \ dt\right)^{1/2}$

However, how do we interpret $|\nabla u|$ or even $|\dot u|$ when we are derivatives in the sense of distributions/generalised functions?

Supposedly, a distribution is a functional, and their norms can be calculated like any usual operator.

$$||F||_{B(H_1,H_2)}=\sup_{||h_1||_{H_1}=1} ||Fh_1||_{H_2}$$

which in our case would be $$||\dot u||=\sup_{||h_1||_{\mathcal{D}(\Omega)}=1} |Fh_1|_{\mathbb{R}}$$,
where $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ is the space of test functions. What would be the norm in $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$?

Comment: What exatly is  $u$? An element of $L^2(\Omega)$? Which type of object are we talking about?

Comment: @StarBug Yes, we can assume it as such.

Comment: Btw $\cal{D}(\Omega)$ is not a normed space (there is no norm). But is does have a topology. A distribution in general is (linear) functional $F:\cal{D}(\Omega)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is continuous with respect to this topology. For $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ the gradiant $\nabla u$ defines a distribution in the sense $F(\phi):=-\int_\Omega u\, \mathrm{div}\phi\,dx$. I am not sure $|\nabla u|$ is always well defined as a distribution though. You probably need that $\nabla u$ at least defines a complex measure.

Comment: @StarBug thanks for the comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suppose you are working with $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$? I don't know if this is the most correct interpretation, but it is very useful in a lot of applications. You know how to define, given $u \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ the distribution 
$T_{u} \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ by $$T_{u}(\varphi) = \int{u(x)\varphi(x)}dx$$ and then you define $\frac{\partial T_{u}}{\partial x_{i}}$ in the distributional sense.  It may happen to exist $g \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ such that $\frac{\partial T_{u}}{\partial x_{i}} = T_g$, in this case, we say $g = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}$ in the distributional sense and $$\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}\right\|_{L^{2}} = \|g\|_{L^{2}}$$ with this norm being the usual in $L^{2}$.

In this way, if $\nabla u = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{1}}, ..., \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{n}} \right) \in [L^{2}(\Omega)]^{n}$ we define
$$ \|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}}^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}\right\|_{L^{2}}^{2}}$$
You find more about this on books dealing with Sobolev spaces.

(Edit: I hope this answer your question, I am not sure if I got what is your doubt)

Comment: I'll read this tomorrow. It's already late where I am. Thanks for the answer. ;)

Comment: After reading your answer, I'm still left with a doubt. The derivative of $u$ in the distribution sense is defined by $<\dot u, \phi>=<u,\dot \phi>$. You're saying, if there's a function $g$ with $<g,\phi>=-<u,\dot \phi>$, then we can do $||\dot u||_{H}=||g||_{H}$

Comment: There's a "-" (minus) missing in my first equality

Comment: In a certain way, yes. This is what we define as Sobolev Spaces. So, for instance, the space $H^{1}(\Omega)$ (you'll also find this denoted by $W^{1, 2}(\Omega)$) is the space of all $u \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ such that, for all $i = 1, ..., n$ $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}} \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ (by this I mean the function $g$ in my answer is in $L^{2}(\Omega)$) and the norm in $H^{1}(\Omega)$ is defined by $\|u\|_{H^{1}}^{2} := \|u\|_{L^{2}}^{2} + \|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}$ (here, again, I reefer to my answer for the notations I am using).

Comment: There are other Sobolev Spaces, as $W^{m, p}(\Omega)$ with $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, so take care with what you mean with this norm. Please, take a look at Brezis' Functional analysis book for more information. The reason I said "in a certain way" is that $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ isn't a normed space and in general it is much more interesting the analysis of Sobolev Spaces when dealing with distributions and distributional derivatives.

Comment: Last comment: If we try to define $\nabla F$ using the following equality $<\nabla F, \phi> = - <F,\text{div} \phi>$, it doesn't seem to be consistent with the above definition, since $<G, \phi> = - <F,\text{div} \phi>$ does not in general define completely the components $G_i$.